# Droidcam on Ubuntu22.04 not Working [Video Device not found]

Tags: droidcam

I tried to install Droidcam on Ubuntu 22.04 following instructions on https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/ but when I open it this error pops up : Droidcam/v4l2loopback device not found(/dev/video[0-9]).Did it install correctly?
If you had a kernel update, you may need to re-install.
I uninstalled and reinstalled it but the same error keeps coming up.
when I try to connect to my phone with it an error pops up saying "missing video device"
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To install v4l2loopback:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

Got the solution from here [modprobe v4l2loopback fails on Ubuntu](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/59)

During the install of v4l2loopback-dkms I had to do the ['Enroll MOK'](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) process (it guided me automatically).

After this I uninstalled and reinstalled Droidcam and the webcam was registered with no error

Comment: I am also using Ubuntu 22.04 and had this exact same error message come up. The solution provided by Bodena indeed worked for me. Thanks Bodena.